# cx_freeze exe have issue with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cx-freeze

[image]i'm using cx_Freeze for the first time, and i'm facing an issue with numpy.
after i build the application with cx_freeze, whene i run the .exe file, i got this error in the image

i'm using numpy in my software, and obviously that's what make the problem, i wrote a litte software that uses numpy just for testing, and i built the .exe, and it gives me the same error, any help please ?

Comment: Can you use numpy in a normal Python script? Given the first lines of the error message, it appears the relevant DLL file is not installed, hence numpy won't work.

Comment: thanks @Evert for your answer, but yes i always use numpy, i do machine learning, so i use numpy in all my codes, and it works fine, but when i use cx_freeze to generate the .exe, i get that error message

Comment: If may be some path settings that Anaconda sets up correctly for you, and lets it find the correct DLL, but the exe may not find it. Check your environment variables when using Python within Anaconda, and go from there. This is more a Windows administration issue; I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: i tried to include numpy in the setup.py but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest posting your setup.py but guessing based on a similar error I had previously, check that you have included numpy in the build_exe_options["packages"].